# User authentication in a next js 13 project using firebase

Tags: firebase, authentication, next.js

I'm trying to protect certain pages. I've set up an auth context provider:

```
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import {
    onAuthStateChanged,
    getAuth,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { firebase_app } from '@/lib/firebase-client-config';

const auth = getAuth(firebase_app);

export const AuthContext = React.createContext({});

export const useAuthContext = () => React.useContext(AuthContext);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({
    children,
}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        console.log("Callback triggered. User:", user);
        if (user) {
            setUser(user);
        } else {
            setUser(null);
        }
        setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
}, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>
            {loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Which I've wrapped the layout.tsx in. However in my pages where I'm checking the user status, the comparator seems to be returning false when the user is null. Or at least, I don't know how user is stored as.

```
export default function MyPage() {
  const user = useAuthContext()
  const router = useRouter()
  console.log(user)
  console.log(user===null)      
  React.useEffect(() => {
        if (user == null) router.push("/login")
    }, [user])
  return (
```

The first console log shows a json file? with user:null as its only element. However the second log returns false. I've set the if (user==null) to if(true) and it pushes fine, so it seems to just be a problem with the comparison logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out. user was not the actual user value, but the whole context object. So I just needed to destructure the user with { user }.

For some reason my IDE is showing it as an error pre-compilation though saying user does not exist on type {}, however it seems to run fine. Not sure. Maybe it has something to do with me mixing js with ts files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).